# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established error while creating a secure websocket connection

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, websocket

I am trying to create a secure websocket client and server.

Server code:

```
var options = { 
    key: clientKey, 
    cert: clientCert, 
    ca: caCert,
    passphrase: 'test',
    requestCert: true
}; 

var httpsServer = https.createServer(options);

var WebSocketServer = WebSocket.Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
        verifyClient: (info) => {
            console.log('Request from client :'+ info.req.rawHeaders);
            console.log('Request from client auth :'+ info.req.client.authorized);
            success = !!info.req.client.authorized;
            return success;
        },
        server: httpsServer
});
```

Client Code:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8989/',
          'com.hp.cdm.service.ioFilter.version.1.type.filterStream', {
            cert: fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(serverCertPath)),
            key: fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(serverKeyPath)),
            ca: fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(caCert)),
            passphrase: 'test',
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          });
```

When I try to make a connection from client to server, I am getting the following error,

```
{ Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1086:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
code: 'ECONNRESET',
path: undefined,
host: 'localhost',
port: '8989',
localAddress: undefined }
```

What am I doing error? Any TLS version mismatch? Or some certificate error?

Comment: What is the soln for this @shaik